# Javascript - Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, class

So I have major problem with importing from one class to another and what I have done is in my "main" class which I call

**detailsPage.js**

```
import { DetailsPage } from '../tests/detailsPageObj';

const utils = require("../utils/utils");
const assert = require('../node_modules/chai').assert;
const userData = require('../globalContent.json');

describe('Details page', function () {
    const detailsPage = new DetailsPage();

    // The details page is accessible by the specified URL
    it(`Is defined by the URL: ${userData.url}`, async function () {
        await detailsPage.navigate();
    });

    // Details page has a form and it can be filled out with user data
    it('Has a form that can receive user data', async function () {
        await detailsPage.fillFormWithUserData(); // If you want, make the user data passable to the method
        await utils.click(detailsPage.form.buttons.nextStep);
    });

    if (detailsPage.hasStockConflict) {
        // Details page allows the user to fix conflicts in stocks
        it('Enables resolution of stock conflicts', async function () {
            // Wait for stock to fully load
            await browser.sleep(2000);
            await detailsPage.clickAllRemoveButtons();
            await detailsPage.clickAllDecreaseButtons();
        });
    }

    // Details page allows the user to proceed to the next stage when all conflicts (if any) has been resolved
    it('Allows the user to proceed to the next stage of purchasing', async function () {
        const nextStepButton = detailsPage.form.buttons.nextStep;
        await utils.elementToBeClickable(nextStepButton);
        await utils.click(nextStepButton);
    });
});
```

and what I am trying tod o is to get DetailsPage from another script which is called:

**detailsPageObj**

```
import { element, by } from 'protractor';

const utils = require("../utils/utils");
const userData = require('../globalContent.json');

export class DetailsPage {
    get pageUtils() {
        return {
            qtyRegex: /^Sorry.*?(\d+)/
        }
    }

    private get fields() {
        return {
            email: element(by.id('email')),
            firstName: element(by.id('firstName')),
            lastName: element(by.id('lastName')),
            postalCode: element(by.id('postalCode')),
            addressOne: element(by.id('addressOne')),
            addressTwo: element(by.id('addressTwo')),
            phone: element(by.id('phone')),
            businessCustomerCB: element(by.id('isBusinessCustomer')),
            company: element(by.id('company')),
            GST: element(by.id('gst')),
        }
    }

    private get groups() {
        return {
            address: element(by.css('div#addressGroup.input-container.showHiddenGroup'));
            company: element(by.id('companyGroup')),
        }
    }

    private get modals() {
        return {
            contactModalLink: element(by.id('contactModalLink')),
            cross: element(by.className('modal-cross')),
        }
    }

    private get formButtons() {
        return {
            nextStep: element(by.id('submitIdentityFormButton')),
            mobile: this.mobileFormButtons
        }
    }

    private get mobileFormButtons() {
        return {
            continue: element(by.id('stock-conflict-continue-button')),
            removeOutOfStockItems: element(by.css('button[id="removeOutOfStockItems"]')), // I just assumed that this is a part of the form
        }
    }

    private get productFrameMobileButtons() {
        return {
            stockControll: element.all(by.className('stock-controller mobile')),
            remove: element.all(by.className('btn btn-remove btn-outlined mobile')),
        }
    }

    private get productFrameDesktopButtons() {
        return {
            stockControll: element.all(by.className('stock-controller desktop')),
            remove: element.all(by.className('btn btn-remove btn-outlined desktop')),
        }
    }

    get form() {
        return {
            fields: this.fields,
            groups: this.groups,
            buttons: this.formButtons,
            modals: this.modals
        }
    }

    get productFrame() {
        return {
            buttons: {
                decrease: element.all(by.className("btn left")).first(),
                mobile: this.productFrameMobileButtons,
                desktop: this.productFrameDesktopButtons
            }
        }
    }

    get errors() {
        return {
            stockConflict: element(by.className('generic-error-heading')),
        }
    }
}
```

and what I am trying to do is in detailsPage.js im  trying to import detailsPageObj.js but whenever I am trying to do it I do get `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

What am I doing wrong

Comment: Why is there a need to mix `import` and `require` statements? Did you try it with `require`?

Comment: no I haven't but I thought maybe it is different when it comes to importing from another class? @Prasanna

Comment: It looks like you are trying to run this code in a web browser instead of in protractor.

Comment: @Quentin I realized that I have mixed it up a bit and forgot that it didnt work this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is your environment like, but I experienced a similar problem where my environment used a full build step for creating the target JS code from my sources (e.g. from TypeScript or from ES6+) to a bundled/plain JS.

But then my test environment did not have any build step. So when I executed the tests, it only understood plain JS, which by default in a node.js environment does not recognize `import` but only `require`.

You can use `import` in your node.js code without a build step, but you need to follow some steps, e.g. rename your file from *.js to *.mjs. More details [here](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html).

Comment: Yupp that was my problem. I managed to solve the issue by converting it to Javascript correctly :)